# Reworking the divs

Tags: html, css

First post so I am unsure of the format works for post but I have created a site as a newbie in which I got it to work on desktop but when on mobile, the right hand side of the website goes over another text instead of under. Any thoughts? I have trouble with getting the side bar update to appear where I want to. The solution now is to add the code between two left side divs which in turn, when minimized, the stripo goes over there divs and the following ones.

My trouble is that if i put the div at the end of the code, then the div only appears next to the last div then going down. The website is http://clinicalresearch-apps.com/index.html. Thank you.

**HTML CODE**

```
 <div class="col-md-5">
    <br>
    <div class="navigation">
        Center for Biostatistics Updates
        <br>
        <div class="my-text">
            <p><font size="4"> Application cycle open for our Center for Biostatistics-sponsored 1-year MS in Biostatistics Program in Theory and
                Methods! Learn more here
            <br>
            <p><font size="4">Apply now for our Center for Biostatistics-sponsored 1-year MS in Biostatistics
                Program in Clinical Applications geared specifically for clinically-trained professionals! Learn more here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.navigation
    {
        position:absolute;
        left: 20px;
        padding-left: 10PX;
        background-color:#221f72;
        opacity: .9;
        width:502px;
        height:745px;
        color:white;
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `<font>` - it isn't 1994 anymore. Use a style for `<span>` or some other appropriate element. Use `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc for headers.

Comment: The `<center>`, too, is obsolete. Remove the (obvious) comment before the doctype as it may cause issues with some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

First off let me say good job for creating the site as newbie, many comments on what you could be doing better but awesome start, everyone starts somewhere.

Your have two main issues:
1) Your class of "navigation" is causing issues with it's current rules.
2) You are not utilizing bootstrap html/css correctly.

First update your class to something like this:

```
.navigation {
    background-color: #221f72;
    opacity: .9;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Removing the `position : absolute` solves a lot, let the element flow naturally.

Add this for your video iframes, particularly for mobile:

```
.navigation iframe { width: 100%; }
```

Next, since you are already using bootstrap, utilize it correctly. Bootstrap specifies that you should place columns inside of rows, and your rows inside of a container. You have columns and a container, but not rows around your columns!

You looks like you want to have the main column be `col-md-7` and the right/side column be `col-md-5`, surround both of these with a `<div class="row"></div>`, then seeing what you get. Remember to refer to the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

Answer (score -1):

Use media screen, you can control it through its width size. Make the position relative instead of absolute

Comment: This will most likely make no sense to the OP as they are new to developing. Could you provide examples in your answer to help?